# Minitest for get request with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

I'm having trouble with one of my tests, even though the controller is working perfectly.

So, I have a form to change the VIP status of an user.

```
<%= form_tag("/activate/#{@user.id}", method: :get, class: "form-inline space-bottom") do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :vip, false %>
    <%= check_box_tag :vip, type:"checkbox" %>
    <%= date_field_tag(:vip_expiration_date, @user.vip_expiration_date) %>
    <button type="submit">
        Change
    </button>
```

This form sends to this route:

```
get  '/activate/:id',           to: 'users#activate_vip'
```

and gets to this controller action:

```
def activate_vip
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(activate_vip_params)
    flash[:success] = "VIP status updated"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render show
  end
end
```

also:

```
def activate_vip_params
  params.permit(:vip_expiration_date, :vip)
end
```

And this action works just fine, no problems, so I wanted to make a test for it using minitest:

```
  test "Admin should be able to change vip status" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get "/activate/#{@other_user.id}", params: {:vip => true}
    assert @other_user.vip
  end
```

I was sure this test would simply pass, but I'm getting the error "Expected false to be truthy."

My intuition said it's related to how I pass the parameters, so I tried several variations on params: but all without success. Can someone help me on this one?

I'm using gem 'minitest', '~> 5.10', '!= 5.10.2' and rails 5

EDIT:

Changed the code so I could "require" the user.

```
    <%= form_for @user, url: "/activate/#{@user.id}", class: "form-inline" do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :vip, false %>
    <%= f.check_box :vip, type:"checkbox" %>
    <%= f.date_field :vip_expiration_date %>
    <%= f.submit "Change" %>
    <% end %>
```

and the controller

```
def activate_vip_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:vip_expiration_date, :vip)
end
```

and the test:

```
test "Admin should be able to change vip status" do
  log_in_as(@user)
  patch "/activate/#{@other_user.id}", user: { vip: true } 
  assert @other_user.vip
end
```

Still no success. The controller works but can't make the test.

------ EDIT ------

Nevermind. It was a stupid mistake.

I just had to add "vip:false" in the fixture for @other_user do initialise the variable.

Comment: Consider explaining and accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> You don't have to use 'params', you need to write permitted parameter name. For ex in your controller

```
def address_params
  params.require(:address).permit(:street_address_1)
end
```

> Then in test case you can do

```
    test "Admin should be able to change vip status" do
      log_in_as(@user)
      get "/activate/#{@other_user.id}", address: { street_address_1: "1223 4th floor"}
     assert @other_user.vip
    end
```

Comment: I changed the form so I could write as "params.require(:address).permit(:street_address_1)" but had no success.

Comment: Can You add debugger before get statement and copy the response over here.

Answer (score 1):

It was a simple mistake.

Everything was indeed correct, but the fixture for `@another_user` needed a `vip: false` status so the variable could be initialized.